# I want to log different messages all the time whenever i log. So what changes can be made in the below code

Tags: java, linux, spring, unix

```
public class Example {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
       
    public static void init(){
           FileHandler fh;
           try {
               fh = new FileHandler("/Users/hp/Desktop/example1.log");
               //fh = new FileHandler("/Users/hp/Desktop/example1.log", true); //this is for appending the file

           logger.addHandler(fh);
           SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
           fh.setFormatter(formatter);
           
           logger.info("Logger Initialized");
           } catch(Exception e) {
               logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Exception ::", e);
           }
       }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        init();
        try {
            int a = 10/0; //for Arithmetic Exception
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception ::",e);
        }
        logger.info("End of program");
    }
```

In the above code whenever I log, I am getting the same messages in the text file but I want the different messages to be logged. At least that freedom should be there to make the changes. This method i tried what can be the other ways to do that..?

Comment: Please help me with the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes to this part of the code as such:

```
try {
        int a = 10/0; //for Arithmetic Exception
    }
catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception ::",e);
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "<Your desired message here>");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry in the above made changes it is printing different logs not the different messages.

Comment: The above changes is only responsible for printing the Exceptions.